# Does my nearsightedness come into play when creating light outlines in the distance?

Tags: eyes

After looking at a light and closing your eyes, you see an outline of the light. I was curious how my nearsightedness would come into play. I look at a light in the distance without my glasses on and close my eyes, would I be able to distinguish the light shape better than if directly looking at the light?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Since this is a question about your personal response to light is there something stopping you from testing this yourself? Note that we encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you might still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

Not likely.  The afterimage you see when you close your eyes is an effect dependent upon which light-receiving cells in the retina (rods and cones) saw light when your eyes were open.  The blurry image you saw when your eyes were open has the same size and shape as the afterimage you see when you see when you close your eyes.  Because the afterimage has less detail, perhaps you would be less distracted by detail and be able to pay more attention to shape, but it seems unlikely that would noticeably help your idea of the shape.